# How to write the response in a file with JSON format using python?

Tags: python, json, file-read

I am trying to store the response from API in JSON format. I got the JSON response in a string format and stored in a file. How do I make it or convert with indent as we see in the onlineJSONViewer application? or in JSON format.

Code I used to store in a file.

```
    def test_url(self):
       resp =requests.get(www.myurl.com)
       data = resp.text
       f = open("19octfile.json", "w")
       f.write(data)
       f.close()
```

This Code stores the response in 19octfile.json in below format:

```
{"data": [{"id":"myname","id":"123","name":"myname","user":"m3","provider":"user","region":"india"}]}
```

Now, How can I store the response with indent i.e in JSON format so that user can understand easily when reads.

My different TRY but in vain:

```
        with codecs.open('data.json', 'w', 'utf8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False))
```

#### This code give the same result with unicode character no indent

```
       with open('17octenv71232111.json', 'w') as outfile:
           json.dump(data,outfile)
           outfile.close()
```

#### This code also same result with unicode char and no indent

Can any one help me is there any library that can do the format work or any code to help.

Comment: you can pass indent parameter with value as int

Comment: Sorry , can you please explain in detail i am not getting how to use int

Comment: @dow reading the manual would be faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) accepts a named parameter `indent`. From the documentation:

> If indent is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, or negative, will only insert newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation.

First you need to load the json file contents into a python object. Your current code is passing the json string to json.dumps. Use the following:

```
j = json.loads(data)
f.write(json.dumps(j, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Here the [json.loads](http://j%20=%20json.loads(data)%20f.write(json.dumps(j,%20sort_keys=True,%20indent=4))) function turns the json string into a python object which can be passed to `json.dumps`.

Comment: Great!!! thanks for teaching me! I learnt that we need to first load and then only print for our desired requirements

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
d={"data": [{"id":"myname","id":"123","name":"myname","user":"m3","provider":"user","region":"india"}]}
print(json.dumps(d,indent=2))
```

To write to file

```
with open('17octenv71232111.json', 'w') as outfile:
   outfile.write(json.dumps(d,indent=2))
```

Comment: Nope, I tried but in same string paragraph format with \ all over.I need to write in file not print in cmd prompt